# Accessing objects in a client server setup

Tags: java, c++, oop, concept

I am wondering if an idea i have in mind is possible in object oriented programming.Let us say i have a client (A) on a certain ip address i.e 192.168.1.105 and a server (B) on ip address 192.168.1.101. Would it be possible to access objects in client (A) and possibly modify an object of my choice on the same client from server (B) ?.Is there a technique in c++ or java or any other major language i can use to achieve this ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several technologies that allow you to do that but I guess you mean language independent [CORBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture) or Java's RMI. Also have a look at remote EJB calls etc.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have sockets opened you can use them to exchange messages between client and server. This messages may be interpreted to do what you need.

E.g.: a message with a known content issued from client to server causes an object on the server side to change!

However, this seems quite obvious, maybe you meant something else (Remote Method Invocation)?